# ¿Como eliminar elemento especifico de un arreglo de objetos? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Buenas capos, tengo un problema, espero me puedan orientar, de que manera podría eliminar un elemento especifico de un arreglo de objetos como el siguiente?

```
array = [
{nom: "NOMBRE 1", tipo: "TIPO A"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 2", tipo: "TIPO B"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 3", tipo: "TIPO C"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 4", tipo: "TIPO D"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 5", tipo: "TIPO E"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 6", tipo: "TIPO F"}
];
```

Traté de hacerlo con esta función pero la verdad no tuve exito

```
var borrar = { "nom":""+"NOMBRE 2"+"","tipo":""+"TIPO B"+"" };

array  = array.filter(function(i) {
 return i !== borrar
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es eliminar filtrando y solo obteniendo los items que sean diferentes al pasado para eliminar para eso usamos la función `filter` que nos retorna solo los items que cumplan con la condición que en este caso es si son diferentes al pasado en la variable `cualEliminar` espero te ayude saludos.

**Resumen**

> El método filter() crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.

**Sintaxis**

```
arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])
```

**Descripción**

> filter llama a la función dada callback  para cada elemento del array , y construye un nuevo array con todos los valores para los cuales  callback retorna un valor verdadero. callback es invocada sólo para índices del arreglo que tengan asignado un valor. No es invocada para índices que hayan sido borrados o a los que no se les haya asignado algún valor. Los elementos del array que no cumplan la condición callback  simplemente los salta, y no son incluidos en el nuevo arreglo.

**Ejemplo Funcional**

```js
array = [
{nom: "NOMBRE 1", tipo: "TIPO A"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 2", tipo: "TIPO B"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 3", tipo: "TIPO C"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 4", tipo: "TIPO D"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 5", tipo: "TIPO E"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 6", tipo: "TIPO F"}
];


var cualEliminar = {nom: "NOMBRE 4", tipo: "TIPO D"}

var array = array.filter((item)=>{
  return item.nom != cualEliminar.nom && item.tipo != cualEliminar.tipo
});

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 5):

El problema es el comparar objetos usando `==`, `===` o `!==`:

```js
let obj1={a:1};
let obj2={a:1};
let obj3=obj1;

console.log(obj1==obj2);    // No son el mismo objeto, por tanto la comparación devuelve false
console.log(obj1==obj3);    // Es el mismo objeto
console.log(obj1.a==obj2.a) // Trabajando con tipos primitivos no existe el problema
```

Por tanto, la solución a tu problema es la siguiente:

```js
let array = [
{nom: "NOMBRE 1", tipo: "TIPO A"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 2", tipo: "TIPO B"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 3", tipo: "TIPO C"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 4", tipo: "TIPO D"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 5", tipo: "TIPO E"},
{nom: "NOMBRE 6", tipo: "TIPO F"}
];

function elimina(array,elem) {
  return array.filter(e=> e.nom!==elem.nom && e.tipo!==elem.tipo);
}


console.log(elimina(array,{nom:'NOMBRE 1',tipo : 'TIPO A'}));
```

Comment: Lo entedí perfectamente muchas gracias (Y)

Comment: @Elleiton si la respuesta te sirvió considera marcarla como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores que tengan el mismo problema, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
var idexToDelete;
    list.filter( (item, index) => {
                if (item.nom === "NOMBRE 2") {
                  if (item.tipo === "TIPO B"){
                     indexToDelete = index;
                  }
                }
    });
list.splice(indexToDelete, 1 );
```

O llevarlo a una función lo cual seria mas optimo, a mi parecer.

```
deleteElement(list,elementToDelete){
    var idexToDelete;
    list.filter( (item, index) => {
       if (item.nom === elementoToDelete.nom) {
         if (item.tipo === elementoToDelete.tipo){
          indexToDelete = index;
         }
        }
      });
    list.splice(indexToDelete, 1 );
  }
```

La logia la podrías re utilizar para obtener el index para otro tratamiento que le quieras hacer al dato en particular.